# Open link in opened browser not the default one

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I know it may sound weird but 
 I want to ask if there is a way to open links in opened browser; like link from Mail or other applications...
I have Edge, Chrome and Firefox and each one of them has several opened tabs and when I open a link (from other application) it will opened in Edge by default (default browser).

So I looking for a way to use the already opened browser to open a link instead of opening Edge and load all my opened tabs in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have set a default browser and do not want to change that, I don't think there's a way to do this, but...

There is a utility called Browser Chooser that can be set as the default browser that allows you to choose the browser to open or use each time you click a link. I've been aware of this tool for a while, and it looks like the most recent version (BrowserChooser2) can be set to open specific URLs in a preconfigured browser while unconfigured links will ask which browser they should be opened in.

There also appears to be a utility called Browser Selector available in the Microsoft Store that performs a similar function.

Answer (score 1):

Put your browsers on your `%PATH%` environment variable. Then you can do the following:

- Copy the URL
- open the start menu
- type `<browser name> <URL>` (for example `firefox https://example.org`, use pasting for the url)

If the URL has spaces or other charactes that might be misinterpreted put the URL in double quotes like `<browser name> "<url>"`.

All browsers I have tried (`firefox`, `vivaldi`, `msedge` for edge) accept a url as the first argument and they will open that url in an existing browser window if there is already one.